# Php str_replace and stripslash not working to remove backslash

Tags: php

This is array in which i have to pass static values based on conditions.

```
$allRequired  = array();

$allRequired[0]= "delhi";
$allRequired[1]= "chandigarh";
$allRequired[2]= "Mumbai";
```

After this i have implode this array

```
$result = '"' . implode ( '", "', $allRequired ) . '"';

$data = array('required'=>array(trim($result,'"'))); 
$msg="OK";
```

and i am getting response

```
{
    
    "MESSAGE": "OK",
    "RESPONSE_DATA": {
        "required": [
            "delhi\", \"chandigarh",\"Mumbai"
        ]
    }
}
```

But i need response to be

```
{
    
    "MESSAGE": "OK",
    "RESPONSE_DATA": {
        "required": [
            "delhi", "chandigarh","Mumbai"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `$allRequired = "delhi","chandigarh","Mumbai";`  - _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ","_ Please make the information you supply sensible and real

Comment: Don't write a comma-separated string, write an actual array…?!

Comment: no actually this print when i implode array data and i had copied data of  string after implode

Comment: `$allRequired = '"delhi","chandigarh","Mumbai"';` is a string. If you want an array you need to declare it as an array i.e. `$allRequired = [ "delhi","chandigarh","Mumbai" ];`

Comment: Why `implode` it? Go back a step and simply *don't* do that.

Comment: because this is dynamic data from array  and  i have to return it with double quotes in response

Comment: Note how `json_encode` turns **an array** into a properly quoted and bracketed JSON data structure expressing that array. You do not need to manually quote your array. You want to pass an array to `json_encode` so it can properly construct the exact JSON-equivalent of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with an array and then use json_encode() to convert that array to json all will be well

```
$allRequired= ["delhi", "chandigarh", "Mumbai"];
echo json_encode($allRequired);
```

RESULT

```
["delhi","chandigarh","Mumbai"]
```

**Sorry I obviously didnt make my answer clear ...**

If you already have an array `$allRequired` leave it as an array, dont json_decode() it. Add it to the other pieces of data and then Finally if you need it in JSON convert it then, and only then

```
$allRequired = ["delhi", "chandigarh", "Mumbai"];
$data = [   'MESSAGE' => 'OK',
            'RESPONSE_DATA' => [
                'required'=> $allRequired
            ]
        ];

print_r($data);

json_encode($data);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [MESSAGE] => OK
    [RESPONSE_DATA] => Array
        (
            [required] => Array
                (
                    [0] => delhi
                    [1] => chandigarh
                    [2] => Mumbai
                )

        )

)
```

And the JSON will be

```
{
    "MESSAGE":"OK",
    "RESPONSE_DATA":{
        "required":["delhi","chandigarh","Mumbai"]
    }
}
```

Comment: now it returns response like  {
   
    "MESSAGE": "OK",
    "RESPONSE_DATA": {
        "required": [
            "[\"\\\"delhi\\\", \\\"chandigarh\\\"\"]"
        ]
    }
}

Comment: @parv You do not understand what this answer is trying to tell you. You simply do *nothing* with your initial `$allRequired` array. You just do `$data = array('required' => $allRequired)`, where `$allRequired` is still an array `array("delhi", "chandigarh", "Mumbai")`. Done. That's it. Don't `json_encode` it explicitly nor otherwise fiddle with it at this point.

Comment: @parv you are double encoding somewhere. Take a look at your code to find out where. If you are having trouble then update your question with enough detail to help us reproduce your problem. As it stands right now your question is hard to understand because you are hiding too much important information (for whatever reason)